# How do I left justify text between enumerates in LaTex?

Tags: latex

```
\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumi{\Alph{enumi}.}
\item
The \textbf{Definition} of ``Period of Restoration'' is replaced by
the following:

\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumii{\arabic{enumii}.}
\setcounter{enumii}{2}
\item
``Period of Restoration'' means the period of time that:

\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumiii{\alph{enumiii}.}
\item
  Begins:

  \begin{enumerate}
  \def\labelenumiv{(\arabic{enumiv})}
  \item
    72 hours after the time of direct physical loss or damage for
    Business Income coverage; or
  \item
    Immediately after the time of direct physical loss or damage for
    Extra Expense coverage;
  \end{enumerate}

  caused by or resulting from any Covered Cause of Loss at the
  described premises; and
\item
  Ends on the earlier of:

  \begin{enumerate}
  \def\labelenumiv{(\arabic{enumiv})}
  \item
    The day before the opening of the next school term following the
    date when, with reasonable speed and similar quality, the
    property at the described premises should be repaired, rebuilt
    or replaced; or
  \item
    The date when the school term is resumed at a new permanent
    location.
  \end{enumerate}
```

"Period of Restoration" does not include any increased period required due to the enforcement of any ordinance or law that:

I need the last line to line up under b. and it is lining up under (2)

I am getting this:

[image: Result]

Comment: I am a new contributor and new to LaTex and for some reason the last line did not publish with my code and I am not able to edit the post. This is the last part of my code:                                                                 \item
        The date when the school term is resumed at a new permanent
        location.
      \end{enumerate}
 
``Period of Restoration'' does not include any increased period
      required due to the enforcement of any ordinance or law that:

Comment: For TeX related questions it is probably better to ask them at [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need two \end{enumerate} 's after the "The date ... permanent location." line.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
    \def\labelenumi{\Alph{enumi}.}
    \item
    The \textbf{Definition} of ``Period of Restoration'' is replaced by
    the following:

    \begin{enumerate}
        \def\labelenumii{\arabic{enumii}.}
        \setcounter{enumii}{2}
        \item
        ``Period of Restoration'' means the period of time that:

        \begin{enumerate}
            \def\labelenumiii{\alph{enumiii}.}
            \item
            Begins:

            \begin{enumerate}
                \def\labelenumiv{(\arabic{enumiv})}
                \item
                72 hours after the time of direct physical loss or damage for
                Business Income coverage; or
                \item
                Immediately after the time of direct physical loss or damage for
                Extra Expense coverage;
            \end{enumerate}

            caused by or resulting from any Covered Cause of Loss at the
            described premises; and
            \item
            Ends on the earlier of:

            \begin{enumerate}
                \def\labelenumiv{(\arabic{enumiv})}
                \item
                The day before the opening of the next school term following the
                date when, with reasonable speed and similar quality, the
                property at the described premises should be repaired, rebuilt
                or replaced; or
                \item
                The date when the school term is resumed at a new permanent
                location.
            \end{enumerate}

        \end{enumerate}

        ``Period of Restoration" does not include any increased period required due to the enforcement of any ordinance or law that:

    \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The first \end{enumerate} got you from being aligned with the T in "The date when the school term...." to being aligned with the (2). You need one more to get you out to align with the b.

If you need to pick up the list from where you left off (3c, 3d, etc.) further down, you can do it using \setcounter so that it doesn't start over again at a; here's an example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{enumerate}

Text Text Text

\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{3}
\item pickup where left off
\item text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small macro called unclip.

Used with all lowercase, it will end a list, write the given contents, and resume the list.
Used with uppercase U, it will gather the enumeration-number before writing the contents and restore it when resuming the list.

```
\newcommand{\unclip}[2][enumerate]{\end{#1}#2\begin{#1}}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Unclip}[2][enumerate]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@saveenum@\romannumeral\@enumdepth}%    create temporary counter
    {\newcounter{saveenum@\romannumeral\@enumdepth}}{}%
  \setcounter{saveenum@\romannumeral\@enumdepth}%        store item number
    {\value{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}}%
  \end{#1}#2\begin{#1}%                                  end list, write content, resume
  \setcounter{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}%             restore item number
    {\value{saveenum@\romannumeral\@enumdepth}}}%
\makeatother
```

You can stack it for multiple levels. Be aware that it may give an error if you stack it, unless you use an \item[] after each inner call. It will still compile though.

Extensive example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\unclip}[2][enumerate]{\end{#1}#2\begin{#1}}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Unclip}[2][enumerate]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@saveenum@\romannumeral\@enumdepth}%    create temporary counter
    {\newcounter{saveenum@\romannumeral\@enumdepth}}{}%
  \setcounter{saveenum@\romannumeral\@enumdepth}%        store item number
    {\value{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}}%
  \end{#1}#2\begin{#1}%                                  end list, write content, resume
  \setcounter{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}%             restore item number
    {\value{saveenum@\romannumeral\@enumdepth}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item TestItem A
  \begin{description}
    \item[preparation] No Item-number yet, so only smallercase unclip
    \item[test] and action:
    \unclip[description]{This should be below \textit{TestItem A}}
    \item[Test] And now inside a enumeration:
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item One
      \item Two
      \Unclip{This should be under \textit{Test}}
      \item Three
      \Unclip{But now we are stacking, by calling
        \textbackslash Unclip\{\textbackslash unclip[description]\{text\}\}
        \unclip[description]{so this should be under \textit{TestItem A}
        \\Be aware it will raise an error, eventhough it works fine.
        \unclip[itemize]{And while you can have text in front of an inner unclip,
        doing it the other way round would seriously fuck up your layout.}}}
      \item Four
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Unus
        \item Duo
        \item Tres
        \Unclip{Yes, you can \Unclip{unclip multiple
          \unclip[description]{levels just fine.
          \unclip[itemize]{Still works. :-)}}}}
        \item Quattuor
        \Unclip{\Unclip{\unclip[description]{\unclip[itemize]{By the way:}
          \item[]You can get rid of the errors,}\item[and] stack it back in}
          \item[] by using \textbackslash item[] after the inner unclips}
        \item Quinque
        \item \dots
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{description}
  \item TestItem B
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I hope it helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `\noindent` 
You just have an indent ;)